# SoX - mixing two audio tracks but looping/repeating only one

Tags: linux, audio, sox

I have two audio-files and want to mix them with **`SoX`** using the `-m, --combine mix` option.

Both files have the same bpm, but not the same length, meaning I need to loop one file, but not the other. Does anyone on here know (if possible) how to do this?

I managed to create a looped file with **`sox`** by using the `repeat` option, but I can not use this option only on one input file,

somewhat like:

```
sox -m repeat 4 one-bar.flac four-bar.flac outfile.flac
```

also a **pipe** does not work:

```
sox one-bar.flac repeat 4 | sox - -m four-bars.wav output.flac
```

I get:

```
sox FAIL sox: Not enough input filenames specified

sox FAIL formats: can't determine type of  `-'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got to use the **pipe** option `-p, --sox-pipe` otherwise the first command is not passing anything to `stdout` and the second command only gets one file for mixing:

```
sox FAIL sox: Not enough input filenames specified
```

Using a pipe with the `-p` option does the job:

```
sox one-bar.flac -p repeat 4 | sox - -m four-bars.wav output.flac
```